# Where to declare simple variables in a Jetpack Compose activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to execute a certain action whenever the internet connection is reestablished in my application, and I do that only if the internet has been down for more than 30 seconds.

I still want my code to be lifecycle aware of the main activity, as I think it's good practice.

I'm just unsure where to declare the `hasBeenOfflineForMillis` variable in the following code, or should I approach this whole thing differently?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor

    private val mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var hasBeenOfflineForMillis: Long = 0

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                networkMonitor.isOnline
                    .onEach {
                        hasBeenOfflineForMillis = if (!it)
                            System.currentTimeMillis()
                        else
                            System.currentTimeMillis() - hasBeenOfflineForMillis
                    }
                    .collect {
                        if (it && hasBeenOfflineForMillis > 30000) {
                            TODO("Sync repositories")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        // Other code...
    }
}
```

Comment: There are different ways to do it but in a nutshell none of that logic should be in the activity. You need to split the responsability between VMs, UseCases, DataLayer classes and Framework classes like the implementation of the NetworkMonitor. And this doesn't have to do with Jetpack Compose. It would have been the same with the Layout UI framework

Comment: I need to launch that somewhere tho, so I should launch it in the view model?
And is it safe to declare the variable in the view model then?

Comment: If you don't care that time counter will be reset on configuration change (e.g. screen rotation) then you're fine. Just move the code to separate function for better readability, like `refreshDataOnIntetnetChanges` and make the `hasBeenOfflineForMillis` instance variable. But probably a better place for that kind of code would be inside Application class, which is not related to any particular screen.

Comment: Logically the hasBeenOfflineForMillis doesn't seem to have to do with the screen so I wouldn't put it in the VM either. And I don't think it should have to do with the lifecycle of the activity. It has to do with the network connection.

Comment: Since I only care about the network when the activity is displayed, I think taking into the account the lifecycle of it is important. Otherwise if I put it in the Application class, it runs even if the application is in background, which is not a thing I need.
Or am I wrong saying that?

Answer (score 1):

You should move the logic to your viewmodel and use a `DefaultLifecycleObserver` to monitor the lifecycle of the activity,

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val networkMonitor: NetworkMonitor,
) : ViewModel(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private var networkJob: Job? = null
    private var hasBeenOfflineForMillis = 0L

    override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        networkJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            networkMonitor.isOnline
                .onEach {
                    hasBeenOfflineForMillis = if (!it)
                        System.currentTimeMillis()
                    else
                        System.currentTimeMillis() - hasBeenOfflineForMillis
                }
                .collect {
                    if (it && hasBeenOfflineForMillis > 30000) {
                        TODO("Sync repositories")
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        networkJob?.cancel()
        networkJob = null
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity2 : ComponentActivity() {

    private val mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycle.addObserver(mainActivityViewModel)

        // Other code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tysm, I already ended up with this solution but instead of using the `viewModelScope` I used the `owner.lifecycleScope`. That way I don't think I need to cancel the job on the `onStop` method as the coroutine already folllows the lifecycle of the activity.
Thanks a lot anyway, and correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm right, I'm gonna post my solution as the answer, or you can modify yours so that I can accept it.

Comment: I would not consider it best practice to use a scope (from the LifecycleOwner) in the viewmodel when the viewmodel does not own said scope. You may not want to cancel and restart whatever you are doing on rotation or on any other configuration change, which will happen if you use an activity based scope.

Comment: Can you link any documentation about it? I tested it and the rotation doesn't make the coroutine restart, I think you are wrong about that